# axios patch request 'success' but data has not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, crud

I am having a bit of trouble implementing a patch request into a react app that uses axios and useContext.

I am getting my data from my node/express api that I have made available to the component via a context provider.

Reading the data is fine but I am in the process of implementing the other crud operations and getting myself a little stuck.

My onChange handler for the input logs out the change made, I am then storing those values using   useState locally and then passing the updated value to my patch request with my saveUsers function when the form is submitted. Although I get a code 200/ success message the data hasn't changed. I believe I am not passing the updated data correctly but despite trying different solutions I appear to be going around in circles.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```js
const { usersData } = useContext(UsersContext);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  const [userValues, setUserValues] = useState(usersData);

  const [name, setName] = useState(selected[0].name);
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  const saveUsers = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userDetails = {
      Name: name,
      Phone: phone,
      Email: email,
    };
    console.log('userDetails', userDetails);
    const selectedUser = selected[0]._id;
    console.log('selected', selectedUser);
    const options = {
      method: 'patch',
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      url: `${BASE_URL}user/${selectedUser}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    const res = await axios
      .patch(`${BASE_URL}users/${selectedUser}`, userDetails, options)
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.status === 200, ' User Updated');
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    setIsLoading(false);
    setReadOnly(true);
    // history.push('/userList');
  };

  return (
    <form
      className={classes.root}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
      onSubmit={saveUsers}
    >
      <div>
        <TextField
          disabled={isReadOnly}
          label="Name"
          defaultValue={selected[0].name}
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            readOnly: isReadOnly,
          }}
        />
```

In this example I have tried updating the username from Alexander Tom Jones to just Alexander Jones.

console output:

[image: output]

Comment: On React side, I think everything looks fine. We can see that the request contains the updated data (in ```config``` prop), but the response not. Are you sure everything is correct with your server?

Comment: server is fine, all working with postman.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to get rid of 'userDetails' and replace with the key/values directly after '.patch(`${BASE_URL}users/${selectedUser}`, {name: name, phone: phone etc etc}'

But I think there should be a cleaner way to do things.

Comment: So it might be that the server expects lower-case property names? Whether it's a variable or object literal shouldn't matter.

Comment: tried that and also value : value shorthand and they both don't work. Suggestion appreciated though.

Comment: Tried to reproduce in a codesandbox, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-fog-1opro?file=/src/App.js Works as expected. Note that if I change the name of the property from lowercase to start-uppercase (Title vs title), it would return object with 2 properties named title, but different in casing.